# NSIS "Bad text encoding" compilation error from _EndSwitch macro

Tags: nsis

We've been using NSIS 2.50 for some time now and I'm trying to update to the newest 3.0x version. I'm using `Unicode true`. I've ran into an issue, which I'm failing to understand. We use a switch for mapping native language names to language IDs, more or less like this:

```
${Switch} "${LANGNAME}"
    ${Case} "${LANGFILE_ALBANIAN_NAME}"
        StrCpy $0 "${LANG_ALBANIAN}"
        ${Break}
    ${Case} "${LANGFILE_ARABIC_NAME}"
        StrCpy $0 "${LANG_ARABIC}"
        ${Break}
    ; Other cases
${EndSwitch}
```

The error I'm getting from compilation:

```
Bad text encoding: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\nst9352.tmp:9
!include: error in script: "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\nst9352.tmp" on line 9
Error in macro _EndSwitch on macroline 9
```

The temporary file is apparently created by LogicLib, which then tries to include it. The file really doesn't have any valid Unicode encoding (I'm posting just a snippet from the file):

```
!insertmacro _== `$2` `Shqip` _LogicLib_Label_433 ""
!insertmacro _== `$2` `???????` _LogicLib_Label_434 ""
!insertmacro _== `$2` `Catal�` _LogicLib_Label_441 ""
```

The strings with invalid UTF-8 characters seem to be encoded in various ANSI encodings (some seem to be Western European, some Central European etc.), while the question marks are saved as real question marks (0x3F). `${LANGFILE_NLFID_NAME}` is defined in language files as native name using the `LANGFILE` macro from `LangFile.nsh`. I looked at the language files and they are encoded in UTF-8 BOM and look all right. So it looks like the native name is re-encoded to ANSI or something for `${LANGFILE_NLFID_NAME}`?

I'm pretty sure I'm making some stupid mistake, but I can't really figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug, it will be fixed in the next release.

Since you are not using the fall-through Switch feature you can just use Select or If/ElseIf instead:

```
${Select} "${LANGNAME}"
    ${Case} "${LANGFILE_ALBANIAN_NAME}"
        DetailPrint LANG_ALBANIAN
    ${Case} "${LANGFILE_ARABIC_NAME}"
        DetailPrint LANG_ARABIC
${EndSelect}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you.